# Create offline bitcoin tx for p2pkh address in a user-friendly way?

Tags: raw-transaction, utxo, p2pkh, offline

You created vanity  `p2pkh`-addresses in the past, you have access to the private keys (`WIF`) and addresses (1...).

Now you want to spend the funds securely and in an offline way (you do not want to enter your private key into an ONLINE computer).

I imagine something like:

- You enter the `p2pkh` address (ONLINE), the program fetches the UTXOs and
  creates a list of transactions and an unsigned transaction
  to spend the inputs to a given address.
- In the next step you can sign
  the transaction (OFFLINE) and export the signed transaction.
- In the
  last step you submit the TX to the network.

Are there any user-friendly tools/programs that offer this functionality?

Comment: I believe this is how pretty much any offline wallet program works. You use the private-key-less online wallet to generate whatever is needed for the transaction, then you transport the transaction to the offline one to sign it

Comment: The big difference is that most offline wallet programs are using BIP39 HD wallets.
Here I want to "solve" this problem for a dump private/public key pair.

Answer (score 1):

I think `electrum` is perfect here among its functionalities it is user friendly and it support offline transactions for P2PKH addresses securely and also offline transaction signing.

You can have more information on the official website https://electrum.org/#home